# What could be the meaning of "doctor-testing of little girls" by Steinbeck?

Tags: meaning, john-steinbeck, east-of-eden

I was reading *East of Eden* by John Steinbeck, where I came across the sentence:

> A man’s mind vagued up a little, for how can you remember the feel of pleasure or pain or choking emotion? You can remember only that you had them. An elder man might truly recall through water **the delicate doctor-testing of little girls**, but such a man forgets, and wants to, the acid emotion eating at the spleen so that a boy had to put his face flat down in the young wild oats and drum his fists against the ground and sob “Christ! Christ!” Such a man might say, and did, “What’s the damned kid lying out there in the grass for? He’ll catch a cold.”

I understand that the overall meaning is that we remember the good and simple things, but not the struggles and pain that were also present.

Still I struggle with the meaning of "the delicate doctor-testing of little girls"; what did the author mean by that?

Comment: I don't think the testing of little girls by doctors (the phrase written out) is about playing doctors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect that what is being referred to is the euphemism of "[playing doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_doctor)".

> "Playing doctor" is a phrase used colloquially in the Western world to refer to children examining each other's genitals. It originates from children using the pretend roles of doctor and patient as a pretext for such an examination. However, whether or not such role-playing is involved, the phrase is used to refer to any similar examination.

This fits well with the mention of [wild oats](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sow+wild+oats) at a later age, where such experimentation becomes more fraught with emotion and complication.

Comment: Didn't notice the detail about the _wild oats_, that is a nice touch. I accepted as it makes perfect sense.